# MS OneNote drawings

Tags: onenote

I work with *.one files using [MS-ONE]: OneNote File Format, [MS-ONESTORE]: OneNote Revision Store File Format and I am stuck in parsing drawing elements.

I found several unknown JCID codes (0x00060014, 0x0002003b, 0x00020047, 0x00120048) and PropertyIds (0x00001daa, 0x00001d4f, 0x00003415, 0x00001d4e, 0x00003416, 0x00003409, 0x0000340b, 0x0000340a, etc) which are not described in the official specification. I was trying to find some accordance between these codes, their content and Ink Serialization Format, but almost any good results.

Maybe, someone could give some tips to direct me in a correct way of parsing OneNote drawings.

Comment: Could you provide us with relevant code samples for how you are attempting to parse them now? What language are you using, and could you provide some sample files and a short, self-contained, complete example of your parser, so we can try to replicate the error?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja thanks for your attention. Actually it is not an error, I want to highlight a lack in the official specification (you can check [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd924744%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - no nodes related to drawings, but MS OneNote application allows to use it)

Comment: And I am looking for a person, who has some experience in parsing these undocumented elements.